# Step-up power module XL6009 converter and >4Amp power source!

Tags: arduino, led, 12v

I want to power up for an hour or two a 6W LED panel (17,8V at 200mAh) from a 12v 7Ah gel battery. I want to use a DC-DC step up convertor with XL6009 to increase the voltage (made in China, Ebay, Amazon), like this:

[LINK EBAY HERE](http://www.ebay.es/itm/252477833148?ul_noapp=true)

[image]

This module only allows for a max of 4Amp input and my DC battery goes up to 7Ah and 120Amp peak. Can I still use the module given the low discharge rate (low LED panel power consumtion)? How can I make this safe to work and not burn in ashes?

Thankful in advance,
Sam

Comment: Post a link to your LED panel and someone might be able to sort your figures out. May the Holy smoke bless that person.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the way to evaluate this. Your LEDs will consume 3.56 watts (17.8 volts * 0.2 amps). The battery must supply this power. But the battery is at 12 volts (perhaps slightly more) so there will be 0.3 amps (3.56 watts / 12 volts) drawn from the battery through the boost converter. And actually it is a little more than that since the boost converter burns up some power as well. If we assume it is 90% efficient then the amps on the battery side will be 0.33 amps (0.3 amps / 0.9).

The battery supplies amps to a load. The less amps drawn, the longer the battery will last before needing recharging. Your battery is rated at 7 Ah.  This is calculated over a 20 hour period for most batteries. This means 0.35 amps for 20 hours (7 Ah / 20 hours). But you will be drawing 0.33 amps. So your battery life will be about 21 hours (7 Ah / 0.33 amps).

Take care when using a boost converter such as this. Left unattended, it can draw down your battery voltage to the point of damaging the battery. So stop using your LED when the battery voltage drops to 10.8 volts and then start charging the battery. If you would like your battery to support more charge/discharge cycles, bump that limit up to 11.6 volts.

Comment: Hi Glenn. VERY thankful for your answer, but I was not asking this (though I can tell you it is USEFUL to me anyway!). 

What I am asking is if the battery Amp being greater than the max. Amp capacity of the step-up module can damage module itself. Module withstands <4Amp and battery can provide up to 120Amp. That's my fear!! Will my battery fry the module even if I connect to its output a <4Amp low-power LED?

Comment: No chance of damage - the load draws amps (current) from the battery, the battery doesn't push amps to the load. So the load determines the current.

Comment: Ahhh!!! That's what I thought, but I could not assess it!! Thank you Glenn again. God bless and have a nice day. You have been so kind!!

Comment: Happy to help. Don't forget to put a small fuse (4 to 5 amps) as close as possible to the positive battery terminal. A small automotive blade type fuse and holder would work well for this.